# Autocomplete textview detect change in text

Tags: java, android

So basically i've got markers place on the google map. When i select an item on the list, these markers are cleared.

If the user, say delete his input at the `autocompletetextview` or change his input, i would want the markers be placed again (call `initsearch` again, which means if the user selects an input again after input change/delete, markers will be cleared again)

I tried textwatcher and onNothingselected but they didn't work the way i wanted them or maybe I implemented them wrong.

Need advice on how to implement this.

```
private void init(){
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonArrayRequest arrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            URL + "all", new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            for (int i = 0; i<response.length(); i++){
                try {
                    JSONObject plantObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    plantLocation plantLoc = new plantLocation();
                    plantLoc.setPlantName(plantObject.getString("plant"));
                    plantLoc.setLatitude(plantObject.getDouble("latitude"));
                    plantLoc.setLongitude(plantObject.getDouble("longitude"));
                    LatLng latLng =  new LatLng(plantLoc.latitude,plantLoc.longitude);
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(latLng)
                            .title(plantLoc.plantName));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d("Error", error.getMessage());
        }
    });
    queue.add(arrayRequest);
}

private void initSearch() {
    init();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, plantList);

    AutoCompleteTextView actv = findViewById(R.id.input_search);
    actv.setThreshold(1);
    actv.setAdapter(adapter);

    actv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String selectedItem = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
            Log.d("your selected item",selectedItem);
            mMap.clear();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't completely follow the premise of your question.  How did the markers get there initially?  And then how do they get added again later?

Comment: i called an init funtion, as shown above, which places markers (latitude and longitude are parsed from a json file) they are called in the start of initsearch function. If the user say changes input/delete input, i want to call initsearch again (which also calls init, places markers again, and awaits for itemclick again)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do that by using the listener for autoCompleteTextView:

```
yourAutoCompleteTextViewRef.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
    {
        //add call to method here
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int 
    after) {                

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```

Comment: When i do that, markers are back, just like i wanted, but whenever I try to search again,click a selection, it prmopt the app to not respond

Comment: are you saying the app crashes? can we get the error if so?